# willTransitionToTraitCollection not called while traitCollectionDidChange is

Tags: ios, uikit

I don't understand what could be the reason for `willTransitionToTraitCollection`not being called in my controller, since the traitCollection do actually change, since `traitCollectionDidChange`is called.

Thanks.